# Sorting an array that is asynchronously loaded - Ionic2+

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-observables

Newbie here. In my Ionic 2+ component I have the following method that, given an array of keys and another parameter, gets the corresponding user profiles from the database through a service function called `getUserProfileService(uid,gid)` which returns an `Observable<UserProfile>` (which contains only 1 user profile):

```
getUserProfiles(uids: string[], gid: string) {
  uids.forEach((uid, index) => {
    this.db.getUserProfileService(uid, gid).subscribe(profileObj => {
      this.membersProfiles[index] = profileObj;
    })
  })
}
```

The var `memberProfiles` is of type `UserProfile[]` and it is initialized to `UserProfile[]=[]`.

Now, I would like to **sort()** the array `this.membersProfiles` according to a specific sort function. 
How can I process the entire array before it is displayed in the template?

Comment: `this.memberProfiles.sort`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "asynchronous array"; I think you mean an array that is asynchronously loaded. The obvious answer here is to sort the user profiles in the `getUserProfileService` function... Although you mention that it only contains 1 user profile, so sorting doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, I'm sorry. Language barriers. I meant an array that is loaded asynchronously.

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes but where in the code? The array is not already there when I try to sort it

Comment: So basically I ended up processing the array when the last element of `uids` is processed. However I would appreciate any other suggestion